# jquery datepicker has different format on different browsers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

im using jQuery datepicker in my php code specifically for the browsers like IE and Firefox. The default date format of datepicker is mm/dd/yyyy, however for chrome, since the date picker is already available, it shows dd/mm/yyyy. Whatever the display format is, i only want to send back to the server 'yyyy-mm-dd' or as in php date('Y-m-d)

How can i display the date from datepicker as dd/mm/yyyy and send to database as yyy-mm-dd? In doing so, i don't want to affect Chrome which is already working properly. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: could you post the code where you initialize the datepicker?

Comment: How are you "sending back to the server"?  How are you "sending to the database"?     If you're sending to server via javascript (as per tags) then you can parse it/reformat it before sending.  You could also parse the date server-side before sending to the DB.

Comment: How are you formatting your `<input>`?  Chrome will (incorrectly IMO) draw a date box differently if it's `<input type='date'>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`dateFormat`](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats) option:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( 
  "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd"
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Set your `datepicker` format try this :-

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", 'yy-mm-dd' );
```

[More details](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats)

Comment: Hi, Thank you, you solved my problem of 3 hours. It works. I will accept this answer. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify `dateFormat` other wise its dependent to browser.

```js
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#format" ).change(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
    });
  });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Format date</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30"></p>
 
<p>Format options:<br>
  <select id="format">
    <option value="mm/dd/yy">Default - mm/dd/yy</option>
    <option value="yy-mm-dd">ISO 8601 - yy-mm-dd</option>
    <option value="d M, y">Short - d M, y</option>
    <option value="d MM, y">Medium - d MM, y</option>
    <option value="DD, d MM, yy">Full - DD, d MM, yy</option>
    <option value="&apos;day&apos; d &apos;of&apos; MM &apos;in the year&apos; yy">With text - 'day' d 'of' MM 'in the year' yy</option>
  </select>
</p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Reference: [jqueryui datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Rahautos. I did this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (datefield.type!="date"){     jQuery(function($){         
    $('#datepicker').datepicker(); 
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", 'yy-mm-dd' );        
})

}
</script>
```